# i was trying to get text on the right side and i did it but when shrinking the screen size it text is overlapping with the image

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Obja.png)
when screen size is normal

problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN5N3.png)
when resizing the screen

I want the text to stay on the right side of the image all the time and never overlap in desktop and mobile

html
I also used bootstrap

```
<div id="moreNews" class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 row rowCard">

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="assets\images\image-retro-pcs.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 moreNewsCol">
      <h2 class="moreNewsH2 ">01</h2>
      <h3 class="moreNewsH3 ">Reviving Retro PCs</h3>
      <p class="moreNewsP ">What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 row rowCard">

    <div class="col-lg-4 moreNewsCol">
      <img class="imageSize" src="assets\images\image-top-laptops.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 moreNewsCol">
      <h2 class="moreNewsH2 ">02</h2>
       <h3 class="moreNewsH3 ">Top 10 Laptops of 2022</h3>
       <p class="moreNewsP ">Our best picks for various needs and budgets.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 row rowCard">

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="imageSize" src="assets\images\image-gaming-growth.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 moreNewsCol">
      <h2 class="moreNewsH2">03</h2>
       <h3 class="moreNewsH3">The Growth of Gaming</h3>
       <p class="moreNewsP ">How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6% 12% 6% 12%;
}

#moreNews {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.imageSize {
  width: 6rem;
}

.moreNewsH2{
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 85%;
  color: hsl(233 8% 79%);
}

.moreNewsH3{
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.moreNewsP{
  text-align: left;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.moreNewsCol{
  text-align: left;
}

.rowCard {
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
}

.attribution {
  margin-top: 6rem;
}
```

I spend hours messing with code but I didn't got the solution

I want the text to stay on the right side of the image all the time and never overlap in desktop and mobile

Comment: prevent using float because there are better methods to obtain the same thing

Comment: Use css [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)